# Estimate $|a+b|^p + |a-b|^p$

Tags: analysis, estimation

I want to show, that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, p \in \mathbb{N}$ one has the following inequality:
$$|a+b|^p + |a-b|^p \geq 2 |b|^p$$

I tried to use the binomial formula and triangle inequality, but got stuck on my way, as I only get
$$\geq |(a+b)^p+(a-b)^p|= 2 \left|\sum_{k=0, k \text{ even}}^p \binom{p}{k} a^{p-k}b^k\right|$$.

How can I continue? Or am I on the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the fact that the function $f(t)=|t|^p$ is convex, we have
\begin{align}
|b+a|^p+|b-a|^p
&=2\big(\tfrac12f(b+a)+\tfrac12f(b-a)\big)\\
&\ge 2f\big(\tfrac12(b+a)+\tfrac12(b-a)\big)\\
&=2f(b) = 2|b|^p.
\end{align}
To see $f$ is convex, note $f''(t)=p(p-1)|t|^{p-2}\ge 0$. This suffices for all $p\ge 2$. For $p=1$, you can prove $f$ is convex using the triangle inequality, or just prove the inequality directly.

Comment: Nice proof! In particular this shows that the inequality is true for any real $p\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   using the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), for $\,p \ge 1\,$:

$$
\sqrt[p]{\dfrac{|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p}{2}} \ge \dfrac{|a+b|+|a-b|}{2}
$$

What's left to note is that $\,|a+b|+|a-b| \ge 2|b|\,$, which follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: Should be $|1+\lambda|^p$, no?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Indeed. Fixed, thanks..

Comment: This is almost correct, but when $\lambda=0.01$, neither $|1+\lambda|$ nor $|1-\lambda|\ge 2$. I think you know how to fix it, though.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Quite obvious, now that you mention it ;-) Thanks, reworked.